# dose Google AJAX Language API have frequency limited?

Tags: frequency, google-translate, google-language-api

i have many documents need to be translate,so i want to know is there some frequency limitation for this api,i didn't found any relevent information,any advice is welcome

Answer (score 0):

im not 100% sure but i know the soap api has a 1000 calls perday limitation  i would assume the ajax api has something similar applied to it but again im not 100% sure on that